# How to access data returned by .where ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I've started using ActiveRecord to access my database and it is extremely useful. However, accessing the data inside an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object seems to be a challenge. I query my database using:

```
post '/login' do
    session.clear
    r = User.where(:username => params["user"], :password => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params["pass"]))
    if r.count == 1 
        session[:user] = r
        session[:user].delete(:password)
        status 200
    else
        status 401
    end
end
```

With the data returned, Ruby checks to make sure there is one row, and if so, sets the content of the `r` object to the hash `session[:user]`. Then, ideally, it should delete the password data from the `session[:user]` object so that it only provides details to identify the user. However, using this code, I get the error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` pointing to the `.delete` line. So, how can I delete the password data from this object, or convert it to a hash, as I know I can delete the password in hash format.

Comment: You can use User.select('row1,row1').where(:username)...rather than delete attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling delete on the relation, not in a hash or a user.

As said by @sunny1304 you can select the fields to get from the database, and also you have to call #first to retrieve only one entry.

```
r = User.where(:username => params["user"], :password => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params["pass"])).select(:id, :username, :other_attrs).first
```

You shouldn't store all the user data in session anyway. You should save only the id, and maybe something that does not change, (for example a username if it exists in your app). And query for the user data on every request.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip on the session data. I will definitely implement that.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to reidentifying users, I usually use only store a single unique attribute in the `session` object which can't easily be tampered with (in Rails, the session is stored in a—now signed and encrypted—cookie). The amount for data is usually limited in session stored.

For this purpose, add a `token` to my Users table which will be regenerated **each time the user logs in** and stored in the session. Usually (on PostgreSQL) I'd define this column of type `uuid`, but you could also use a `VARCHAR(128)` or similar.

If the user now returns, I just issue a

```rb
@current_user = User.where(token: session['user_token']).first
```

When the user logs out, I just nullify the user's `token`:

```rb
@current_user.update_attribute :token, nil
session.clear
```

Comment: I have that implemented using the user ID like Ismael said. But when I use `@current_user.first` to get specifically the first name, I get this: `{"user":{"birthday":868282140,"email":"test@test.com","first":"Test","gender":1,"id":3,"last":"User","password":"passwordinMD5","username":"test"}`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord queries return a relation, not an array or an object - think `select`, `collect`, etc. `session[:user] = User.all.select{|u| u.id == 1}` doesn't really make sense, does it?

So, like the above said:

```
User.where(:id => 1).class == ActiveRecord::Relation
```

while

```
User.find(1).class == User
```

This is done so that when you chain queries, ActiveRecord can turn them into one SQL query, instead of fetching many, many records, turning them into Ruby objects, and then running Ruby commands on them.

For a really simple example:

```
$ User.where(:id => 1).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1
=> 1
```

versus:

```
$ User.where(:id => 1).all.count
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1
=> 1
```

That `.all` converts the ActiveRecord::Relation into an array of Ruby objects, in this case, `User`

Then you can do

```
User.find(1).update_attributes(:name => "Joseph")

user = User.find(1)
user.name = "Jack"
user.save
```

because it's a Ruby object.